# What solutions are there for adjusting text in an app without having to dive into code? [React Native]

Tags: react-native, localization

First of all this is my 1st stackoverflow post so sorry if I am missing context or do if the question is too out of the ordinary.. Onto some context and example use case for my question.

**Context**
I'm making a simple app for an uni assignment in React-Native but one of the requirements client we are making it for is that the text (copy) in the app can be adjusted by him after we deliver it to him.

**Example Use Case**
They want to change the text on the welcome screen from "Welcome, [Name]" to "Hello there, [Name]". But they aren't technical so they expect to be able to change this in a simple UI.

I've tried googling for solutions but keep finding Localization solutions instead and all I've found so far require in-code edits.

Example:
  [react-native-localize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-localize) & [Expo Localization Docs](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/localization/)

Any help/pointers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic ways to solve this issue.

1. Create an API that the app calls to get the text. Make web or app tools for the client to edit the text in the API. This is usually called a CMS (content-management solution).  There are a huge range of options, including building your own.

Pros:

- the client can maybe manage their own content without intervention... sometimes
- content changes are "instant" -  without an app release

Cons:

- non-trivial to plan and set up
- requires support/maintenance
- additional costs for hosting
- additional app complexity (need to think about error states, caching, polling?)
- app NEEDS to be online to have content

OR

2. The client submits a ticket for the text changes and a developer makes them.

Pros:

- doesn't require the creation/ maintenance of additional tools
- app doesn't need to make network requests for content

Cons:

- changes take longer and require a new release of the app

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for listing out pros and cons for both options!